# Start server, run tests, stop server

Tags: makefile, exitstatus

I have a Makefile target that looks like the following

```
integration-test: git-hooks
    java -Djava.library.path=$$(pwd)/test/integration/lib/DynamoDBLocal_lib \
        -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/dev/null \
        -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=WARN \
        -Dlog4j.com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.server.LocalDynamoDBServerHandler=OFF \
        -jar $$(pwd)/test/integration/lib/DynamoDBLocal.jar \
        -inMemory \
        -port 8000 &
    sleep 3
    ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register \
        --reporter spec \
        test/integration/main.coffee
    ps -ef | grep [D]ynamoDBLocal_lib | awk '{print $$2}' | xargs kill
```

Here's what I'm doing:

- the Java command starts a local instance of Amazon's DynamoDB.
- I give it 3 seconds to start
- I run my integration tests
- I kill the database

What I would like is kill the database regardless of the fact that the tests passed or not.
To do that I suppose I need the exit status of the test command and return that, both if the tests fails or if they succeeded.

What is happening is that if tests pass the database is correctly killed, if the tests fail it's not.

I've read [in the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html#Errors) that you can prepend a `-` in front a command to have `make` ignore it if it produce a non zero exit status, the problem if I do that is that I don't know if the tests failed or not, since `$?` will always return 0.

What's the usual practice in this scenario? I'm fine in splitting the target in more targets if that solves my issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Is "the tests produced an error" and "the tests fail" the same thing? And do the tests write the information you want to stdout? Or do you want the returned value, and if so then how do you want Make to display that information?

Comment: Yes in this case it's the same thing. I want the exit status, yes. Make is already displaying the output of my command, I just want to use the exit status of the test command and return that, I think that by doing this make will in turn return a non 0 exit status, right? I've edited my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to run the entire thing in a single shell, which  means you'll need to use command separators (e.g., `;`) and backslashes to connect the lines.  Then you can store the result and exit with it:

```
integration-test: git-hooks
        { java -Djava.library.path=$$(pwd)/test/integration/lib/DynamoDBLocal_lib \
            -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/dev/null \
            -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=WARN \
            -Dlog4j.com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.server.LocalDynamoDBServerHandler=OFF \
            -jar $$(pwd)/test/integration/lib/DynamoDBLocal.jar \
            -inMemory \
            -port 8000 & }; \
        sleep 3; \
        ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register \
            --reporter spec \
            test/integration/main.coffee; \
        r=$$?; \
        ps -ef | grep [D]ynamoDBLocal_lib | awk '{print $$2}' | xargs kill; \
        exit $$r
```

However, you can actually do even better if you use a single shell, by killing only the exact process you want instead of using `ps`:

```
integration-test: git-hooks
        { java -Djava.library.path=$$(pwd)/test/integration/lib/DynamoDBLocal_lib \
            -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/dev/null \
            -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=WARN \
            -Dlog4j.com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.server.LocalDynamoDBServerHandler=OFF \
            -jar $$(pwd)/test/integration/lib/DynamoDBLocal.jar \
            -inMemory \
            -port 8000 & }; \
        pid=$$!; \
        sleep 3; \
        ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register \
            --reporter spec \
            test/integration/main.coffee; \
        r=$$?; \
        kill $$pid; \
        exit $$r
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you have a link where I can read on the theory behind your solution?

Comment: You can read about recipe syntax here: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipe-Syntax.html  The rest of the changes are not related to make and instead just learning how to program in the shell.  Read your shell's man page are any good shell programming tutorial.